# Forloop behaving weird in javascript but only in firefox and ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

This works fine in chrome but not in ie or firefox when i trace this in firefox and put cursor on the i inside [i] it shows undefined.

```
var rect1 = document.getElementById(selectedObject).getBoundingClientRect();
var nodes = document.getElementById('c').childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length ; i++) {
    //alert(nodes.length);
    //Don't check selectedObject with itself!
    if (nodes[i] == selectedObject || nodes[i] == undefined) {
        //   alert(nodes[i])
        // alert(selectedObject)
        continue;
    }
}
```

inside [] i is undefined

[image]

outside [] i is 0

[image]

Comment: Does it execute correctly on all platforms? Or are you just concerned about the functionality of the debugger?

Comment: what is `selectedObject`...

Comment: Also `nodes[n]` will never be equal to undefined btw - it's clearly a `DOMNode` as it got retrieved from an elements `.childNodes`

Comment: selectedObject is just the selected div

Comment: it only executes in chrome

Comment: If the HTML is malformed, it can cause this problem as different browsers will error-correct in different ways.  Run your HTML through a validater.

Comment: Page is 100% valid i just checked